# DevExpress Winforms Dashboard - Creating a Rank within Top N

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, greatest-n-per-group, dashboard

I'm new to this forum and this is my first question. I hope someone can help and if you require more information please let me know. I have attached a screenshot to show what I am talking about below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMvRn.png)

For our Dashboard we are Using DevExpress Winforms. We'd like to create a TOP 10 Bar Chart but the Chart should have a numbered Ranking
But the DevExpress Standards do not allow to add ranking or even percentage to the Top N elements, if you are using a bar chart.

Is there anyone who knows how to work around this?

Best Regards and thanks in advance,

Fay